# Editing css with php or JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, css

Is there a way that I can change a css style sheet's data from a html form and php and/or JQuery. So if I have the following

widths.css

```
#main #section1 { 
width: 25%;
}
#main #section2 { 
width: 50%;
}
#main #section3 { 
width: 25%;
}
```

So I want to have 3 text boxes S1, S2 and S3 and then a user can place values into each text box. It will check they add up to 100% or less and then it will write them to the css in place of 25%, 50% and 25%. How would I achieve this using php and/or JQuery.

Thanks

Comment: You won't be able to use jQuery as it is based on JavaScript which runs client-side and cannot change files on a server.

Comment: @ Dan Diplo:you can use javascript or Jquery. Just check for text box values on the client side with javascript and apply hte css accordingly. it is much more clean and easy

Comment: So basically you're trying to make a user configurable interface?  That's nothing new....here's a better implementation:  http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos.cfm

Answer (score 0):

something basic but which should work

```
$(".validate").click(function(){
      //I've assumed your text inputs were children of an element with id section$i 
      var w1 = Number($("#section1 input").val());
      var w2 = Number($("#section2 input").val());
      var w3 = Number($("#section3 input").val());
      if(w1+w2+w3 == 100){
           //here you change css rules for #section$i elements
           $("#section1").css("width",w1+"%")
           $("#section2").css("width",w2+"%")
           $("#section3").css("width",w3+"%")
      }
      else{
           alert("sum of values must equals 100%")
      }
});
```

assuming that you have a clickable area with class `validate`

Comment: Please explain how to use this?

Comment: put this in your document.ready JQuery function() and correct what I've done to match with your markup
Or show your markup by editing the question, then we could provide exact script

Comment: Is this a permanent edit to the css or will it change when I refresh/close my browser?

Comment: that's not a permanent change, as it's done client-side (in the browser). That's a change that occurs in the page which disappears on refresh if you decide so. You can also send the values to the server which can store them and resend them at the next connection

Comment: there's two possibilities for making them persistent. If you want them on a per user base, you can store them in a cookie client-side , or in a database server-side

Answer (score 0):

well there is a dirty but solution to this. use php to write javascript to the the html possibly after ending of body tag.
so the code goes like this

```
..
...
</body>
<?php echo <<< code
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("section1").style.width="$_POST['s1']";
// and then for each section u can do this
code;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to set the CSS dynamically on the page it self. Once the user entered the data, you can use little bit of AJAX to change the styles. So something like below would be your PHP and styles on the page. if you want this to be a permenant change make sure to put the settings in a DB against the user's profile. This can be added to your AJAX script as well.

```
<style type="text/css">
#main #section1 { 
  width: <?php echo $s1; ?>%;
}

#main #section2 { 
  width: <?php echo $s2; ?>%;
}

#main #section3 { 
  width: <?php echo $s3; ?>%;
}

</style>
```

HTH

Comment: Please explain in more detail. Could you write the code please

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `addClass()` to add a specific CSS class with the style you require.

To use PHP, you could use CSS internally on the page:

```
<style type="text/css">
<?php echo "width: 100px;" //for example ?>
</style>
```

But I wouldn't necessarily recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script i just made for you:

```
var merge = function(objectCollections){
    var array = new Array();
    foreach(objectCollections,function(objectCollection){
    foreach(objectCollection,function(object){
        array.push(object);
    });
    });
    return array;
}
var foreach = function(object,loop){
    for (var key in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        loop(object[key],key);
    }
    }
}
var changeCSS =function(value){
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
    var styles = document.getElementsByTagName('style');
    var sheets = merge([links,styles]);
    var rules = value.split(/[(\ *{)(\})]/g);

    for(var i in sheets){
    if(typeof sheets[i] == 'object'){
        var sheet = sheets[i].sheet ? sheets[i].sheet : sheets[i].styleSheet;
        for(var j in sheet.cssRules){
        if(typeof sheet.cssRules[j].selectorText != 'undefined'){
            if(sheet.cssRules[j].selectorText == rules[0]){
            sheet.cssRules[j].cssText = value;
            console.debug(sheet.cssRules[j].cssText);
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

usage example:

```
changeCSS('#main #section1 {width: 25%;}');
```

this will change the css (not set a style on a tag or something)

Comment: its easy, what it does is; find all stylessheets you have and look for the selector you have as a parameter (the "#main #section1") for example this will act just as a css attrebute (sinse it is one).
in other words the paremeter is the css code:
changeCSS('#main #section1 {width: 25%;}');

Comment: not unless u put it in a js cookie but until pagereload all elements with the selectors will be changed yes

Comment: Ok I'm going to have to go the database route then because I need it to be permanent. Thanks